# MySQL DB running in Ubuntu, but not running in Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, ubuntu, innodb, myisam

I have a MySQL DB running in Ubuntu Server (a live server), and it goes well. But I copy the DB folder for development and will run in Windows. When I just copied that DBfolder into my windows-based XAMPP, it doesn't go well. Some table error and "in use" error info on the collation column. The error table engine is InnoDB, and the rest is MyISAM. I'm wondering why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be coping any folder there is a export and import utility for migrating databases from one system database to another system.

Comment: i can not export it because it is a big size database, it is about a hundred gb file.

Comment: It should take you less than a week to export it. The only other option I can think of is you network your windows database to the database that you want on the windows computer.

Comment: ok i see. but i want to know why it is not running in windows when i copy the db folder.

Comment: The analogy is trying to put a motherboard from a proprietary computer into another different proprietary computer it wasn't designed to work with the foreign hardware. Simply it just doesn't work that way.

Comment: so it is only can run in ubuntu?

Comment: yes the file is  tuned so to speak to work with the database in Ubuntu. Export it and import it is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

For InnoDB, there are three choices:

- Copy the entire tree, not just one table or database.  And do it with MySQL shutdown.  This does not allow for any kind of mix and match of tables.
- Replication -- One server is the Master, the Other is the Slave.  But thin, all writes must go to the Master.  And it provides only for maintaining consistency, not for initially providing it.
- "Transportable tablespaces".  This is a way to disconnect a single table (or partition) so that you can copy a file to another server.  Then you perform some other magic to connect the table on the other server.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-copying.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transportable-tablespace-examples.html